# angularjs: returning json data from service to controller

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am using angular js with spring mvc to develop a web application.

It is hitting the spring mvc rest service and bringing data to angular js service, but i am unable to see the same data in service.

controllers.js

```
app.controller('CustomersController', function($scope, customersService){

init();
function init(){
    var data =customersService.getCustomers();
    $scope.customers = data;
}

$scope.insertCustomer = function(){
    var firstName = $scope.newCustomer.firstName;
    var lastName = $scope.newCustomer.lastName;
    var city = $scope.newCustomer.city;
    customersService.insertCustomer(firstName, lastName, city);
    $scope.newCustomer.firstName = '';
    $scope.newCustomer.lastName = '';
    $scope.newCustomer.city = '';
};

$scope.deleteCustomer = function(id){
    customersService.deleteCustomer(id);
};
});

app.controller('NavbarController', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.getClass = function (path) {
        if ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) == path) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
});
```

customersService.js

```
app.service('customersService', function($http, $log) {

this.getCustomers = function() {
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : '/CustomerManagementApp/customers/all'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $log.log('Done');
        angular.forEach(data, function(c) {
            $log.log(c.firstName);
        });
        customers = data;
        return customers;
    });     
};

this.insertCustomer = function(firstName, lastName, city) {
    var topID = customers.length + 1;
    customers.push({
        id : topID,
        firstName : firstName,
        lastName : lastName,
        city : city
    });
};

this.getCustomer = function(id) {

};

this.deleteCustomer = function(id) {

};

var customers = {};
});
```

I am able to print all data using forEach loop in service. But in the controller it shows empty object array Object { }

There is no error in firebug console. I am using POST method. Do let me know if any other piece of code is required.

Comment: make `this.getCustomers` return a promise and use `.then` to chain it in the `init()`.

Comment: @sza: I am very new to angular js... can you please elaborate it little more and post it in the ans, so I can mark it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure. Try this code

```
function init(){
    customersService.getCustomers().then(function(response){
        $scope.customers = response.data;
    });
}

this.getCustomers = function() {
    var promise = $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : '/CustomerManagementApp/customers/all'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $log.log('Done');
        angular.forEach(data, function(c) {
            $log.log(c.firstName);
        });
        customers = data;
        return customers;
    });    

    return promise; 
};
```

> **[promise](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)** - as an interface for interacting with an object that represents the result of an action that is performed asynchronously,
>   and may or may not be finished at any given point in time.

Comment: it worked. I just had to made data.data thanks a ton for insight of promise.